# How can integers (keys & values) be added and retrieved from a NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c

How can I add key (an int) and value (an int) pair to a NSDictionary object? and how can they be retrieved as int?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dictionary key and value has to be a object reference (`id`) so you can't use an integer as the key. You should instead wrap your integers in a `NSNumber`:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]
```

You can then initialize your `NSDictionary` using one of the `initWithObjects` initializers. I chose the `initWithObjectsAsKeys:` initializer which accepts key/values in a value, key, value, key.. nil format.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:15], [NSNumber numberWithInt:5], nil];
```

To access the value, you need to do the same:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]]);
```

**EDIT**: According to your comment, it seems you should be using a NSMutableDictionary, not a NSDictionary. The same thing applies to wrapping your integers, but you'll want to use the setObject:forKey method:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:15] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]];
```

Does that help?

Comment: Your question mentions a NSDictionary. What you need is a NSMutableDictionary. Same thing applies regarding wrapping integers. Use the setObject:forKey method.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap it in an `NSNumber`:

```
int intKey = 1;
int intValue = 2;
[myDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intValue] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intKey]];
NSLog(@"key: %i, value: %i", intKey, [[myDict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intKey] intValue]);
```

EDIT: You need to use an `NSMutableDictionary` to set values. `NSDictionary` can't be modified after it's created.

Comment: The compiler is complaining on line#1:"numberWithInt:forKey not found (return type defaults to id)".

Comment: You probably forgot a closing bracket after intValue.