# how can I call objectForKey from an NSDictionary with an int where the keys are NSNumbers

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, int, nsdictionary

I'm trying to get and set from an `NSDictionary` with `NSNumber`s as the keys.   I think I'm doing things according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6891489/194309 but my code below returns null values.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSInteger const SET1 = 1;
    NSInteger const SET2 = 2;


    videoKeyOfTag = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:SET1], @"well",
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:SET2], @"great",
                    nil];
    NSLog(@"to see well: %@",[videoKeyOfTag objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:SET1]]);   

}
```

I expect `to see well: well` in the log but instead I see what I don't want:

```
to see well: (null)
```

Starting with an `int`, how can I call `objectForKey` from an `NSDictionary` where the keys are `NSNumber`s?

(I eventually want to extract values from the `NSDictionary` with `[sender tag]` as the meta-key.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the numbers to be keys, you need to invert the order in the constructor:

```
videoKeyOfTag = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"well", [NSNumber numberWithInt:SET1], 
                    @"great", [NSNumber numberWithInt:SET2], 
                    nil];
```

Comment: the good news: I also declared tagOfVideoKeys incorrectly, so the fix was simply to switch the variables that receive the newly constructed NSDictionaries

Answer (score 1):

`initWithObjectsAndKeys` - here first argument is value, second one is key. You are doing the opposite. You have used `@"well"` and `@"great"` as keys, not values. You should write:

```
videoKeyOfTag = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"well", [NSNumber numberWithInt:SET1],
                    @"great", [NSNumber numberWithInt:SET2],
                    nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a reason the initializer method is called `initWithObjectsAndKeys:` and not `initWithKeysAndObjects:` (although the latter would make more sense for me, but this is Apple...)
Anyway, the odd-number arguments (1st, 3rd, etc) are the values, the even-numbered (2nd, 4th, etc) are the keys. So try:

```
videoKeyOfTag = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                @"well", [NSNumber numberWithInt:SET1],
                @"great", [NSNumber numberWithInt:SET2],
                nil];
```

instead.

Comment: Yep, the method is named as it works, but dang it's confusing to my little rabbit brain!